# как избежать двойных gap'ов в CSS GRID?

Tags: css, grid

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как сделать чтобы было ровно, gap'ы не дублировались и ширина всего grid'a была фиксированной?

CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: stretch;
    
    
}
.content {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
    /* grid-template-rows: 200px 200px 200px 200px;  */
    grid-template-areas: 
    "a b b"
    "c d e"
    "f f i"
    "g g g";
    
    gap: 1em;
    width: 600px;
    
}

.content img:nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: a;
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    
    
    
   
}
.content img:nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: b;
    
    object-fit: cover;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
   
    
}
.content img:nth-child(3) {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-area: c;
}
.content img:nth-child(4) {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-area: d;
}
.content img:nth-child(5) {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-area: e;
}
.content img:nth-child(6) {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-area: f;
}
.content img:nth-child(7) {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-area: i;
}
.content img:nth-child(8) {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    grid-area: g;
}


img {
    
}

.rate_img
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Бабуленькины котятки</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Бабуленькины котятки</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="poroda_bar">
            <div class="poroda" id="Abys">
                Абиссинская
            </div>
            <div class="poroda" id="Brit">
                Британская
            </div>
            <div class="poroda" id="Rus">
                Русская голубая
            </div>
            <div class="poroda" id="Syam">
                Сиамская
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <img src="https://static9.depositphotos.com/1594920/1090/i/600/depositphotos_10907008-stock-photo-siberian-cat-sitting-in-front.jpg">
            <img src="https://www.royal-canin.ru/upload/articles/1-1_2208.jpg">
            <img src="https://zooclub.ru/attach/42000/42325.jpg">
            <img src="https://catline.ucoz.com/_si/0/74758117.jpg">
            <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-150893132.jpg">
            <img src="https://mokriy-nos.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82-%D1%87%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-3.jpg">
            <img src="https://s1.1zoom.ru/b5753/820/Cats_White_background_Kittens_Tongue_545760_2560x1440.jpg">
            <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/ciOttJ-wruck_wpFgrGkBf3t37p1vM1oP4W5ar2_ahmwciymzBmnQH6cHtr9FvjdfM1tGzi2OdU001UmBlX05X4KFyFpD9Hcx4XpGV8wAGCDzESu0HiP8d0">
        </div>
        <div class="raiting">
            <h3>РЕЙТИНГ</h3>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
            <div id="rAbys">
                Абиссинская
                <img class="rate_img" src="">9
            </div>
            <div id="rBrit">
                Британская
                <img class="rate_img" src="">8
            </div>
            <div id="rRus">
                Русская голубая
                <img class="rate_img" src="">10
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, это не гэпы, а размеры картинок не соответствуют размеру ячейки.
Используйте [object-fit](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit).

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "a b b" "c d e" "f f i" "g g g";
  grid-template-rows: 100px 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 100px 100px 100px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.grid div {
  background: red;
}

.grid div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.e {
  grid-area: e;
}

.f {
  grid-area: f;
}

.i {
  grid-area: i;
}

.g {
  grid-area: g;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="a">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="b">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="c">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="d">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="e">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="f">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="f">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="i">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="g">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="g">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
  <div class="g">
    <img src="https://cdn.mos.cms.futurecdn.net/VSy6kJDNq2pSXsCzb6cvYF.jpg" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, поставил width 100% и height 100% и все получилось